# PDF using WCF Restful Services

Tags: c#, wcf, pdf, rest

Task: To be able to render a PDF when user clicks a link (which is a WCF Service {example: http://localhost:6186/MyReportServices.svc/reports/012}). The Service goes and fetches the report from SSRS Server and returns the Stream. Here is the piece of code that is in .

```
[ServiceBehavior(AddressFilterMode = AddressFilterMode.Any)]
public class AssistReportServices : IAssistReportServices
{
    public Stream GetReport(int value)
    {
      //skipped some lines of code. 
      try
        {
          result = rs.Render(format, devInfo, out extension, out encoding, out mimeType, out warnings, out streamIDs);
          execInfo = rs.GetExecutionInfo();             
        }
      catch (SoapException err)
        {
            throw;
        }
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      ms.Write(result, 0, result.Length);
      ms.Position = 0;
      //WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ResponseType"];
      WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
      return ms; 
    }
 }
```

My Operation Contract looks like:

```
[OperationContract(Action = "*")]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "reports/{value}")]
Stream GetReport(int value);
```

So far so good. But here is the problem... When i click the link above, i get the following error in a dialog box with title Adobe Reader and message:

> File does not begin with '%PDF-'.

Error Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btiql.png

I can save the Memory Stream to a file and manually open the pdf, and it opens just fine without issues.

Thanks.

Comment: The error message looks like it's more of a problem that Acrobat thinks it's opening a file named `012` and not a file named `012.pdf` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found where I was going wrong. I had used the Web.Config file to configure my WCF Service. When i switched to a code based configuration using the following code, the service worked and pointed out my errors as well.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    ServiceHost serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyReportingServices.MyReportServices), ServiceEndpointUri);
    WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
    ServiceEndpoint sep = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(MyReportingServices.IMyReportServices), binding, string.Empty);
    sep.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());
    serviceHost.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Service is running @ " + ServiceEndpointUri);
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press enter to shutdown service.");
    Console.ReadLine();
    serviceHost.Close();
}
```

The error was:

> Operation 'GetReport' in contract 'IMyReportServices' has a path
>   variable named 'value' which does not have type 'string'.  Variables
>   for UriTemplate path segments must have type 'string'.

Which I resolved by changing the datatype for my operation parameters to String.

Thanks to **Mrchief**, as i used his input to add the following line of code, to help me display a Save/Cancel dialog:-

```
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/pdf";
WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=apurvReport.pdf");
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as the answer - answering your own question is valid.

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't allow me to mark the answer until 24 hrs. possibly due to my user level.

Answer (score 0):

How are you sending it to the browser? It looks like its being sent with a wrong mime type. It should go in as `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";`

Comment: Updated the question, the web.config file had the key value pair as:  <add key="ResponseType"  value="application/pdf" />

Comment: Yeah but where are you writing it to the response stream?

Comment: The Service is REST-ful, so I should be able to embed the link http://localhost:6186/MyReportServices.svc/reports/012 as an anchor tag in my HTML page. My Service should stream the response back to the browser, and the browser should prompt an Open Save dialog. Forgive me if my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: So then try adding this header to the response: `Content-disposition: attachment; filename=fname.ext`

Comment: Thanks. I am still not able to achive the results as described in http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/a01680a0-8ffc-4e58-bfe9-6871ef0b2893

Comment: found the answer, but so will not let me post it until 8 hrs due to my user level.