# How To Return PDF From Database In a WCF-Rest Service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wcf-rest

I'm doing a WCF-REST service using C#, which connects with a database in SQL Server to return several tables. Now, I need that my service returns a PDF File, which is stored at the table, in a varbinary(MAX) field. I'm doing some research but I can't found something like I need. How can I implement the service and class to return a PDF File? Thanks

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16027117/how-to-return-pdf-binary-data-from-a-database-in-a-wcf http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819639/pdf-using-wcf-restful-services

Answer (score 1):

**1)** write a method that returns a `Stream` (For ex, a MemoryStream holding your pdf file).

before returning from that method

**2)** Set `application/pdf` to `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType`

**3)** set the length to `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentLength`

Then it should work.

Comment: how can I set the pdf name?

Comment: @anhtv13 `WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" + filename + "\"");`